# jQuery FadeIn / FadeOut inside a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, infinite-loop, fadein, fadeout

I'm using a simple jQuery function to create a small image slider:

```
$( ".grid-item" ).mouseover(function() {
    $(this).find(".slide-image").each(function(index) {
        $(this).delay(800*index).fadeIn(0);
    });
}).mouseleave(function() {
    console.log("Mouse Out!");
});
```

If the function plays once, it stops. Is there a way to loop the function? [Check out my CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bBvedq)!

Comment: I think the problem is that all of the slides are still visible once the the function has run once. You need to hide the slides again after they have been shown becayse if they are not hidden, then they cannot be shown.

Comment: Sounds quite logical! Can you edit my CodePen please?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in your mouseleave function:

$(this).children(".slide-image").fadeOut();

Answer (score 0):

The approach you have attempted has the drawback of queuing up all of the transitions when the user moves their mouse over the images, but you have no way of cancelling those queued transitions when they leave. Also they will only loop through once (I am guessing you'd want it to continue indefinitely). Trigger mouseover several times is going to end up in a weird effect too.

I think you should make use of setInterval and CSS transitions instead and use something like this: http://codepen.io/xram/pen/JbLNNL

```
var gridItemSelector = '.grid-item',
  slideImageSelector = gridItemSelector + ' .slide-image',
  timerId,
  visibleCssClass = 'visible';

$(gridItemSelector).on('mouseover', function() {
  timerId = setInterval(transitionToNextImage, 2000);
}).on('mouseleave', function() {
    clearInterval(timerId);
});

function transitionToNextImage() {
  var $slideImages = $(slideImageSelector),
    visibleImageIndex = $slideImages.index($(slideImageSelector).filter('.' + visibleCssClass));

  $slideImages.removeClass(visibleCssClass);

  if (visibleImageIndex < $slideImages.length - 1) {
    $slideImages.eq(visibleImageIndex + 1).addClass(visibleCssClass);
  } else {
    $slideImages.eq(0).addClass(visibleCssClass);
  }
}
```